# What is the type of an InstanceValue whose InstanceSpecification has multiple classifiers?

Tags: uml

As far as I understood, a UML *InstanceValue* is a value defined by a separate *InstanceSpecification*. In addition, *InstanceValue* specializes *ValueSpecification* and hence *TypedElement*, which means an *InstanceValue* must have a `type`.

However, an *InstanceSpecification* may have **multiple classifiers** in its `classifier` association.

My question:  what is the `type` of an *InstanceValue* whose *InstanceSpecification* has multiple classifiers?

---

**EDIT (23/11):** There is indeed the following sentence in section 9.8.3 of the spec:

> If the InstanceSpecification has one or more classifiers, then the type of the ValueSpecification must conform to at least one of those classifiers.

So should one simply pick any of the classifiers to put as a `type`? Even if it means possibly "hiding" many aspects of the instance?

Comment: Why do you need to understand the UML specification jargon of "InstanceSpecification" and "InstanceValue"? This jargon is only used by UML committee members, but not by real developers/modelers.

Comment: If you want to automatically/programmatically analyze UML models, it is crucial to master its syntax and the semantics of each syntactic concept. A wide range of industries nowadays process UML models in such a way, for instance to generate code stubs or test cases in a systematic way.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding section 9.9.xx of UML 2.5.1, it seems that you do not have real constraint.

But when reading section 9.8.3, I understood that the *InstanceValue* "type" must be conform to at least one *InstanceSpecification* "classifiers".

In one hand if the *InstanceValue* "type"  is not conform to any *InstanceSpecification* "classifiers", the model is obviously wrong. In the other hand *InstanceValue* "type" might be conform to many *InstanceSpecification* "classifiers" but it should be an issue, am I right?

Comment: thanks for the answer! I've edited my question slightly based on your comments

Answer (score 0):

> So should one simply pick any of the classifiers to put as a type? Even if it means possibly "hiding" many aspects of the instance?

Slots represent actual properties of the classifiers. Imagine the following example:

```
class Label {
    public String name;
}

class Identity {
    public Label label;
    public Integer number;
}

class Product extends Identity {
    public String brand;
}
```

And then you are e.g. modeling only the identity aspect. So in the classifiers you specify `Identity` (even though it is an instance of a Product).

[image]

Then you can only have Slots for properties provided from those classifiers, which in this examples means *only* the `label` and `number` properties. Of course you don't need to model all of them, but you cannot add new slots that do not have a corresponding property in the classifiers.

[image]

In other words, you are not "picking" what classifier to use. It is the other way around. The classifiers and their properties specify what Slots you can have.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However I think it might be slightly out the scope of my question, as I was simply questioning the "type" attribute of an *InstanceValue* (section 9.9.10 of the spec, where it does say that its content is given by a separate *InstanceSpecification* element), while here you talk about *InstanceSpecifications* (section 9.9.9 of the spec) and the slots they may or may not contain. Moreover I think what you say is incorrect: an InstanceSpecification *can* have mutliple classifiers, which means it can have slots defined by multiple classifiers.

Comment: But the InstanceValue is associated with a Slot (contained within the "parent" InstanceSpecification), and the Slot determines the type of it. I've never claimed that InstanceSpecification cannot have multiple classifiers. I've only stated that you cannot have Slots for properties that are not in one of the classifiers.